# unable to edit/modify fields in my angularjs form

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-validation, angularjs-forms

I am displaying a form in a modal. But when I click on the text input field it is not allowing me to enter text. similarly unable to change/select radio buttons

But when trying with "**tab**" it is working.

## code

```
<form role="form" name="basicDetails" class="form-validation">
    <div class="col-sm-6 b-r">
      <h3 class="m-t-none m-b font-thin">Basic Details</h3>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email</label>

          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>User Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User Name" ng-model="username" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]{1,17}$/" required>
        </div>

    </div>

     <div class="checkbox m-t-lg">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right text-uc m-t-n-xs" ng-click="ok()"><strong>UPDATE</strong></button>
          &nbsp;
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right text-uc m-t-n-xs" ng-click="close()"><strong>CLOSE</strong></button>

        </div>
      </form>
```

## inspect element shows

[image]
Can someone help me to trace the issue.

Comment: which modal you are using? is it jquery dialog?

Comment: its an angularjs modal. The one we see in https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I am just unaware of how the classes are appended to the form elements. Using Tab's i can change the value, but mouse click events are not working!!

Comment: could you create a plunkr/fiddle that will give more idea to us..

Comment: Ya sure. Will update soon